# EventListener ошибка в консоли при запуске кода

Tags: javascript

Имеется попап, который на момент запуска кода еще не существует в DOM и добавляется он туда только при определенных действиях пользователя (по клику на какую-либо кнопку, например).

У всплывающего попапа есть соответствующий `button`, нажатие на который должно производить закрытие данного попапа, на этом же элементе и должен быть `EventListener`.

Суть проблемы и вопрос:

На момент старта кода, консоль выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Оно и понятно, ведь слушатель "висит на элементе", которого попросту еще нет в DOM, соответственно, поиск равен `null`.

Далее по необходимому сценарию попап добавляется в DOM и все работает без проблем и никаких ошибок не возникает - окно появляется и закрывается.

Вопрос:
Как избавится от возникающий ошибки?

Comment: Вы объект несуществующий скармливаете `addEventListener`.

Comment: если ты знаешь в чем ошибка, почему продолжаешь вызывать addEventListener Тогда, когда элемента еще нет?

Comment: Добавляйте прослушиватель события элементу не при загрузке страницы, а при создании этого самого элемента. Очевидно ведь...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //on(event, future-created-element, function
  $('.main').on('click', '#some', function () { 
      console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<button id="some">Click me</button>
</div>
```